# Start/stop OS X software depending on expensive/free network connection

Tags: gratis, osx, automation

I have two kinds of Internet connections:

- **Expensive**: Based on tethering from my phones, mostly via WiFi/USB/Bluetooth.
- **Free**: Pretty much any WiFi/Ethernet not included above.

I use a app which is useful but takes a lot of bandwidth. I would like to stop it when I connect to **Expensive**, and start it when I connect to **Free**.

Requirement:

- Works on Mac OS X
- Free, ideally open source
- Ability to specify expensive/free connections using medium and WiFi name

Comment: By the way, iOS has a similar feature built-in. In *Settings* app, *Cellular* > *Use Cellular For*. Flip a switch for each app that should or should not use the presumably expensive or limited cellular data access.

Comment: @BasilBourque: Interesting! I wish OS X had this too.